# Requests-html can I get status codes of all requests (or selenium alternative)

Tags: python, selenium, testing, automated-tests, python-requests-html

I have the following code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

ses = HTMLSession()
r = ses.get(MYURL)  # start a headless chrome browser and load MYURL
r.render(keep_page=True)  # This will now 'render' the html page
                          # which means like in a real browser trigger
                          # all requests for dependent links. 
                          # like .css, .js, .jpg, .gif
```

Calling `render()` triggers a load of requests for Javascript, bitmaps, etc.
Is there any way I can get a trace of status codes for each requests.
I'm mostly interested in `404`, but `403` and `5xx` errors might be interesting as well.

One use case would for example be:

• Go to a page or a sequence of pages

• Then report how many requests failed and which urls were accessed.

If this is not possible with requests-html but reasonably simple with selenium I can switch to selenium

**Addendum: ugly work around 1:**

I can setup logging to log into a file and set log level to debug.
Then I can try to parse logs of websockets.protocol: which contains strings like 
`{\\"url\\":\\"https://my.server/example.gif\\",\\"status\\":404,\\"statusText\\":\\"...`

Issues:

Activating log level DEBUG into a file seems to activate something else, because suddenly loads of debug info is also logged into `stdout`.

For example:

```
[I:pyppeteer.launcher] Browser listening on: ws://127.0.0.1:45945/devtools/browser/bc5ce097-e67d-455e-8a59-9a4c213263c1
[D:pyppeteer.connection.Connection] SEND: {"id": 1, "method": "Target.setDiscoverTargets", "params": {"discover": true}}
```

Also it's not really fun to parse this in real time and to correlate it with the url I used in my code.

**Addendum: ugly work around 2:**

Even worse for correlating but nicer for parsing and just identifying `404`s and works just if in control of the http server.

Parsing the logs of the log http server with nginx I can even setup a custom logger in csv format with just the data I'm interested in.

**Addendum: ugly work around 3:**

Using python logging (a dedicated handler and filter for `pyppeteer`) I can intercept a json string describing the responses from the `pyppeteer.connection.CDPSession` logger without having `stderr` become polluted.

The filter allows me to retrieve the data in real time.

This is still quite hackish. So looking for a better solution.

Comment: changed my question: selenium solution is also welcome

Comment: `requests` library can be used to hit URLs and it will give you status-codes .

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat  Thanks for the answer. I know `requests` and use it regularly.

But the whole point of using `requests_html` instead of `requests` is, that `requests-html` starts a headless chrome browser and executes all the javascript.

So what I try to do is to go to a page (as if I open the url in a browser) and get all the http requests triggered that load javascript, style sheets, images.

What I am interested in is not if the request to my url had a certain status code, but what other requests were triggered indirectly and which of these other requests had a status code of 404

Comment: i have heard of `pyCurl` library for getting all resources of a page . never used it myself though. may be you could try that

Comment: I'm rather sure pyCurl is not executing javascript, but can crosscheck once more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try and see if it's what you're after.  It's strictly a pyppeteer version (rather than requests_html) and relies on unexposed private variables so is fairly susceptible to breakage with version updates.

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer.network_manager import NetworkManager

def logit(event):
    req = event._request
    print("{0} - {1}".format(req.url, event._status))

async def main():
    browser = await launch({"headless": False})
    page = await browser.newPage()
    page._networkManager.on(NetworkManager.Events.Response, logit)
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com')
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Checking the source of requests_html the browser page object seems to be buried pretty deep-- so getting at the NetworkManager isn't exactly straightforward.  If you really want it working from within requests_html it's probably easiest to monkeypatch.  Here's an example:

```
import asyncio
from requests_html import HTMLSession, TimeoutError, HTML
from pyppeteer.network_manager import NetworkManager
from typing import Optional, Union

def logit(event):
    req = event._request
    print("{0} - {1}".format(req.url, event._status))

async def _async_render(self, *, url: str, script: str = None, scrolldown, sleep: int, wait: float, reload, content: Optional[str], timeout: Union[float, int], keep_page: bool, cookies: list = [{}]):
    """ Handle page creation and js rendering. Internal use for render/arender methods. """
    try:
        page = await self.browser.newPage()
        page._networkManager.on(NetworkManager.Events.Response, logit)

        # Wait before rendering the page, to prevent timeouts.
        await asyncio.sleep(wait)

        if cookies:
            for cookie in cookies:
                if cookie:
                    await page.setCookie(cookie)

        # Load the given page (GET request, obviously.)
        if reload:
            await page.goto(url, options={'timeout': int(timeout * 1000)})
        else:
            await page.goto(f'data:text/html,{self.html}', options={'timeout': int(timeout * 1000)})

        result = None
        if script:
            result = await page.evaluate(script)

        if scrolldown:
            for _ in range(scrolldown):
                await page._keyboard.down('PageDown')
                await asyncio.sleep(sleep)
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(sleep)

        if scrolldown:
            await page._keyboard.up('PageDown')

        # Return the content of the page, JavaScript evaluated.
        content = await page.content()
        if not keep_page:
            await page.close()
            page = None
        return content, result, page
    except TimeoutError:
        await page.close()
        page = None
        return None


ses = HTMLSession()
r = ses.get('https://www.google.com')  # start a headless chrome browser and load MYURL
html =  r.html
html._async_render = _async_render.__get__(html, HTML)
html.render()
```

Comment: This  works. I tried it out. It might however be more sensitive to version updates of pyppeteer as it is not merely decorating functions, but replacing them.

It is more efficient than me hacking into the logging  (have now a working ugly solution). Your solution might introduce subtle changes in behavior for future versions, whereas my solution would never break pyppeteer, but 'just' break the retrieval of info.

Let's wait a little longer and see if somebody has an idea which is less intrusive and implementation detail dependent than yours or mine.

If not I'll take yours as solution

Comment: There's no guarantee that future versions of either requests_html or pyppeteer aren't breaking as well.  You should probably be pinning versions for anything you care about not changing.